# Two or more words with the same plural

Tags: word-games

Let a *multiplural* be a word that has more than one singular form with different meanings. For example, AXES is the plural of both AX and AXIS and so is a multiplural. I have found these multiplurals:
AXES
ELLIPSES
TAXES

Is there a name for these other than the one I just made up? Are there others without the -ES ending? Can anyone find any others?

EDIT: The new list I have after looking at the answers (and adding one more I missed) is as follows:

AXES

BASES

CAVIES

DOES

ELLIPSES

TAXES

TRIES

Comment: Most of these are not pronounced the same, so they're just ordinary vagaries of English spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Wikipedia article on [heteronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_%28linguistics%29). Its definition includes the phenomenon you are referring to.

> In linguistics, a heteronym (also known as a heterophone) is a word
>   that is written identically but has a different pronunciation and
>   meaning. In other words, they are homographs that are not homophones.

Examples of "multiplurals" are listed in the "Further examples" table.

Comment: The only pair not mentioned by OP is does = deeresses & does = do's.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there are at least two more pairs, although three of these are obscure words:

*Cavies* is the plural of *[cavie](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavie)* and of *[cavy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavy).*

*Tries* is the plural of *[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)* and of *try*.

Answer (score 0):

pastie

> *noun*
>
> 1. **INFORMAL**
>
> a decorative covering for the nipple worn by a stripper.

British pasty

> *noun* **BRITISH**
>
> a folded pastry case with a savoury filling, typically of seasoned
> meat and vegetables.

Both have plural "pasties"

Further reading: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=337